# How to deploy custom PHP MVC website on Hostinger

Tags: php, model-view-controller, deployment, hosting

This is the first time I'm deploying an actual website and I did a project using a custom MVC architecture. Everything is working just fine on local but when I add my files to Hostinger, nothing appears but a blank page. The favicon and the CSS is still loaded in the , though. My hierarchy looks like that:

```
config
- index.php
public
- assets
- .htaccess
- index.php
- logout.php
src
- model
- view 
- controller
templates
- (list of all the things I render with my views)
```

In the index.php located in the config folder, I have all my constants. It looks like that :

```
<?php
// HOST
define("HOST", "https://heptagone-art.com/public/");

// DIR
define("DIR_ASSETS", HOST . "assets/");
define("DIR_CSS", DIR_ASSETS . "css/main.css");
define("DIR_JS", DIR_ASSETS . "js/");

define('DIR_APPLICATION', '../src/');
define('DIR_MODEL', DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/');
define('DIR_VIEW', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/');
define('DIR_CONTROLLER', DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/');

define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '../templates/');

// DB
define("DB_HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME", "(the username hostinger gave me");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "(the password I added on hostinger)");
define("DB_DATABASE", "(the database I added on hostinger");
define("DB_PORT", "3306");
```

I don't really know how to deploy the whole thing properly, and I don't know how to search about it as the information I find don't match with what I did.

Comment: Well I didn't use one when I was still in local so I don't (I only have the .htaccess in the public folder)

Comment: Check your host PHP version if you are using PHP version 8.1 on local and PHP 7.4 on the host. some functions may not work like calling a class dynamically.  enable display error on your index.php.    ini_set("opcache.enable", 0);

Comment: Oh my god, that was it! I spent so much time thinking my folders weren't right but now it just works, the PHP version was 7.4 on Hostinger, thanks a lot!!